# Silent redirect https:\\www.domain to https:\\domain via htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https

I have a site which is using the www (www.domain.com and not domain.com).

But the SSL certificate is valid only for domain.com (https://domain.com). So if I call https://www.domain.com, there comes an error.

My question is, if I can make a **silent redirect from https://www.domain.com to https://domain.com via htaccess?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like LazyOne said:

> Yes, it is NOT possible to do it silently .. as SSL has to be
>   established BEFORE HTTP part can kick in (in other words, before
>   mod_rewrite can execute rewrite/redirect rules).

Answer (score -2):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Taken from http://davidwalsh.name/no-www-using-htaccess-file

Comment: So you want to say, its not possible?

Comment: Yes, it is NOT possible to do it silently .. as SSL has to be established BEFORE HTTP part can kick in (in other words, before mod_rewrite can execute rewrite/redirect rules).